# Non-bootstrap dropdown is cutoff with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I ran into a problem a second ago regarding bootstrap CSS and a custom coded dropdown (not using bootstraps dropdown component). The height of the containing element was cutting off the bottom of the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody runs across this problem, simply set the "container" class element to "container-fluid" and this will solve it. Hope this helps somebody